# req.session is undefined using express-session

Tags: node.js, express

I am just starting to learn how to use cookies with node and express and I would like some help with getting this to work. I tried to follow the [expressjs/session](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession) tutorial on GitHub, however I am getting `req.session` as `undefined`, so I am unable to set or get any values.

My goal is to save the first and last name of a user to a cookie so that an input field will auto populate. I'm not sure if I need to use `cookie-parser` as well or if `express-session` can handle that alone. I'm not sure of how to proceed as I am new to cookies and express-session.

All help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let credentials = require('../modules/credentials.js');
let session = require('express-session');
let sessionOptions = {
  secret: credentials.cookieSecret,
  cookie: {
    maxAge:269999999999
  },
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave:true
};

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1);
  sessionOptions.cookie.secure = true;
}
else {
  sessionOptions.cookie.secure = false;
}

app.use(session(sessionOptions));
let router = express.Router();
app.use(router);

let request = require('request');
let db = require('../modules/queries');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.get('/me', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('req.session: '+req.session);

  let firstName = req.session.firstName;
  let lastName = req.session.lastName;
  if (firstName && lastName) {
    res.render('student/me.jade', {firstName, lastName});
  }
  else {
    res.render('student/me.jade', { firstName: '', lastName: ''});
  }
});

router.post('/api/me', function(req, res, next) {
  let firstName = req.body.firstName;
  let lastName = req.body.lastName;
  // session.firstName = firstName;
  // session.lastName = lastName;
  req.session.firstName = firstName;
  req.session.lastName = lastName;
  console.log('session.firstName: '+session.firstName);
  db.addEvent(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Once you mount a router onto an Express app, any subsequently declared middleware on that app won't get called for any requests that target the router.

So if you have this:

```
app.use(router)
app.use(session(...));
```

The session middleware won't get called for any requests that get handled by `router` (even if you declare the routes that the router should handle at some later point). For that, you need to change the order:

```
app.use(session(...));
app.use(router);
```

An additional issue is that you're exporting `router`, which should probably be `app` (which is the instance that "holds" all the middleware, routers, etc):

```
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Thanks @robertklep - I made the switch. It didn't resolve the issue, but that's helpful to know going forward!

Comment: @RonI `req.session` being undefined is a sign that the session middleware isn't getting called (otherwise, it would populate `req.session` with an empty object). Can you show (in your question) how you add routes/middleware to your app?

Comment: @RonI did you create your project using `express-generator`?

Comment: @RonI see my edit about exporting `app` instead of `router`.

Comment: nice! I didn't see the edit about export app, I made the change and it now works! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

To get session data

first , You have to initialize express-session with

```
app.use(session({ resave: true ,secret: '123456' , saveUninitialized: true}));
```

then When you want to put something in the session

```
req.session.firstName = 'Aniruddha';
req.session.lastName = 'Chakraborty';
```

Then you can check without errors

```
console.log('req.session: '+req.session.firstName);
```

> Note: This is express-sessions work!

Answer (score 7):

This problem occurred with me while trying to maintain `req.session` object in my app. I was setting `req.session.user` in a login route, but was not able to get the same outside that route.

```
console.log(req.session) 
// undefined
```

Since there was no use of `cookie` in my app, I removed it.

***Before removing cookie variable:***

```
app.use(
session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "anyrandomstring",
    cookie: { secure: true},
  })
);
```

***After removing cookie variable:***

```
app.use(
session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "anyrandomstring",
  })
);
```

This resolved my issue. And now I was able to access `req.session` from anywhere in the app.

```
console.log(req.session)
/* Session{
     ......
     ......
    }
*/
```

> **Note:** This issue might also occurs if you have initialized `app.use(session({...}))` at bottom of the file. Try to bring it to the top.

Why this happens: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40324493/10204932)

Answer (score 1):

You will also see `req.session === undefined` if your Redis **connection is invalid or missing**!

I don't see anywhere in your code where connection info is being passed when configuring the session.

Comment: They probably aren't using Redis for their store and are using the default memory store

Comment: Have you found a way around this @jordan-dodson ?

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why this might happen is if you're making requests from a different URL. Make sure your app is running on the same URL as your Express back-end.

Comment: oh my god, thank you. I was going mad for hours what was going on. This helped it for me.