# Passport facebook login: facebook doesn't open, isAuthenticated() false

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js, passport-facebook

Ideally, there is a generic sign in button on the homepage, which redirects to several sign in buttons, one of which is for Facebook. The user clicks that button and, if authenticated, is redirected to `/my-reptiles/`.

However, what actually happens is that when the user clicks "Log in with Facebook", they are not prompted with a confirmation from Facebook and are immediately redirected back to the homepage from the `ensureAuthenticated()` method in `my-reptiles.js`. When running in private browsing, I am asked to log in to Facebook before being redirected, but I am not asked to approve use of Facebook as a login method. Is this normal?

Also a local mongodb entry for the user is still created even though `isAuthenticated()` fails.

On the Facebook developer console I have app domains set to `localhost` and site URL set to `http://localhost:3000/`.

**This is the console output:**

```
GET /auth/facebook 302 4.309 ms - 0
GET /auth/facebook/callback?code=LONG_CODE_HERE 302 215.462 ms - 68
Unauthenticated request!
GET /my-reptiles 302 0.879 ms - 46
GET / 304 14.854 ms - -
```

**This is the network log:**

[image: Network log]

**my-reptiles.js**

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        console.log("Unauthenticated request!");
        res.redirect('/');
    }
}

router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    //Do stuff
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
//Requires here

function findOrCreate(key, cb) {
    db.collection('users').findOne(key, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            if (!user) {
                db.collection("users").insert(key, cb)
            } else {
                cb(err, user);
            }

            db.close();
        }
    });
}

// config
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(
    {
        clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        findOrCreate({
            auth: "facebook",
            id: profile.id
        }, function (err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }
));

var app = express();

//View engine setup here

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser('sekret'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Routes here

const cookieExpirationDate = new Date();
const cookieExpirationDays = 365;
cookieExpirationDate.setDate(cookieExpirationDate.getDate() + cookieExpirationDays);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'sekret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect: '/my-reptiles',
        failureRedirect: '/'
    })
);

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

//Error handling here

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was adding session and passport after my routes, when it should have been before them, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39796445/1653609).

```
//Routes WERE here

const cookieExpirationDate = new Date();
const cookieExpirationDays = 365;
cookieExpirationDate.setDate(cookieExpirationDate.getDate() + cookieExpirationDays);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'sekret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Routes SHOULD BE here
```